# Why don't subshell expressions in ~/.zshenv lead to infinite regress?

Tags: zsh, subshell

I understand that `~/.zshenv` gets sourced every time that an instance of `zsh` starts.

This implies that having the following line `~/.zshenv` would result in an infinite regress:

```
(echo "$$ $(date)" >> $HOME/.debug.zshenv)
```

...because the `(...)` represents a subshell, and hence another sourcing of `~/.zshenv`, etc.<sup>1</sup>

This reasoning notwithstanding, the line shown above is harmless, AFAICT.  In particular, `$HOME/.debug.zshenv` shows only one line after I start a new shell with

```
% zsh
```

Clearly, `~/.zshenv` is not getting sourced anew when the line above is evaluated.  Why not?

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>For that matter, the expression `$(date)` also entails creating a subshell.</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You misunderstand the meaning of subshell. A subshell is not a completely new process but a fork of the existing process.

If you call `zsh` explicitly e.g.

```
zsh -c 'echo "$$ $(date)" >> $HOME/.debug.zshenv'
```

then the shell forks, calls `execve()` and by that starts a completely new shell which does the initialization again.